Effecient Methods for Infinite Series
I'm wondering when doing proofs of some series converging that is it faster to use the regular definition of convergence of the sequence of the partial sums or to use Cauchy criterion. Thanks.

What does faster mean to you in this context?

oh I see, so none is better than the other per se... thx
